# Different page numbering in appendix?

Tags: page-numbering, appendices

How can I use an independent page numbering in the appendix, either with Roman or Arabic numberals as page numbers?

(I.e. the first page of the appendix should start again with 1, as it is often done for the introduction and the main part of a long document, then typically using Roman numerals for the introduction.)

Comment: @85: Which `documenclass` do you use? Most of them are providing the commands `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` to structure the main document.

Comment: I'm using `scrbook`. And `\backmatter` before the appendix.

Comment: @85: Have a look at the [scrguide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguide.pdf) at page 100 or the English one [scrguien](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf) page 80.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To (re)start the page numbering, you need to use the command `\pagenumbering{}`. In all LaTeX classes I'm aware of, the argument of this command can be `arabic`, `roman`, `Roman`, `alph`, or `Alph`.

To automate the process of having the page numbering restart when the document gets to the Appendix (or Appendices), you could include the following instruction in the preamble (using, for instance, lowercase-roman numerals):

```
\let\origappendix\appendix % save the existing appendix command
\renewcommand\appendix{\clearpage\pagenumbering{roman}\origappendix}
```

Comment: You need also a `\clearpage` before `\appendix`.

Comment: Thanks, egreg! I've inserted the `\clearpage` instruction.

Comment: Using this including the suggested `\pagenumbering{arabic}\renewcommand{\thepage}{App.~\arabic{page}}` from a comment below now.

Comment: i suggest using `\pagenumbering` infront of `\clearpage`, this way I can avaoid `destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored<to be read again> \relax l.7 \clearpage [1]` when I use hyperref (note: also be sure to give your titlepage a different pagenumbering than your matter)

Comment: @ted - Did the OP mention or ask about `hyperref`? My answer was based on a lack of mention of `hyperref`...

Comment: @Mico: no he did not, I just thought I leave this here since I came here trying to solve the issue I described.

Comment: @ted -- thanks for providing this clarification. Rather than posting comments on postings that are nearly two years old, you may want to consider posting a new question (possibly with a link to the older postings you've discovered. This'll raise the odds considerably that others will see it too. :-)

Comment: @Mico: Since I managed to solve the issue myself but came here first, I thought it would be resonable to leave a note for the next `googler`. And those who search will hopefully find it.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `\pagenumbering` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

% only for testing
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument

\clearpage
\appendix
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blinddocument

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

This command changes the numbering an resets the counter to 1, even if you’re switching vom arabic to arabic numbering.

Comment: This won't work with `\arabic` numbering if **hyperref** is used; but using two identical page identifiers is bad practice anyway.

Comment: @egreg: Maybe something like A.n is possible, n being the page number?

Comment: Yes: doing `\pagenumbering{arabic}\renewcommand{\thepage}{A.\arabic{page}}` keeps hyperref happy.

Comment: A page numbering style such as "A.\arabic{page}" might become very confusing if you have appendices numbered A, B, and C. To avoid any confusion about whether "A" pertains to "Appendix Section A" or to all appendix sections, it be better to have `\renewcommand{\thepage}{App.~\arabic{page}` instead...

Answer (score 0):

I found that making a simple new command (from the suggestions listed here) works pretty well:

```
\newcommand{\NewAppendix}[1]{
    % put appendix on a new page
    \clearpage

    % reset the page counter
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    % set the format for the appendix page number
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection - \arabic{page}}

    % set the appendix name
    \section{#1}
}
```

You could leave out the `\section{#1}` part if you wanted to just setup for the new appendix. For example, when the `\section{}` command is in a file that you're going to `\input{}` or `\include{}` for the appendix.