# Stop page count before appendix

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, appendices, lastpage

I'm trying to find a way to stop the page count in my report. So the count stops, then it comes to the appendix. Then have a separate count for the appendix, with the footer also changing so when the appendix starts, the page count says (e.g.) Page 1 of 12 pages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different page numbering in appendix?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27846/different-page-numbering-in-appendix)

Comment: @Jake The linked question is not about adding one or several "LastPage" counters.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It probably should have been more of a "Have you looked at (...) yet? Maybe you could show what you've tried so far." comment. So much for duplicate-hunting badges =)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution in case you also want a "lastpage" counter for the main part of your document. Notes:

- I have used the `etoolbox` package to prepend code to the `\appendix` command -- this way, the document body does contain only "semantic markup" and no internal redefinitions.
- Although `report` uses the `oneside` and `openany` class options, my redefinition also gives correct page numbering for `twoside`/`openright`.
- The `emptypage` package will prevent displays like "Page 4 of 3" on an otherwise blank last page of the main part of your document.

---

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page~\thepage\ of~\pageref{LastMainPage}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{Page~\thepage\ of~\pageref{LastMainPage}}%
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\preto{\appendix}{%
  \label{LastMainPage}%
  \ifbool{@openright}{%
    \cleardoublepage
  }{%
    \clearpage
  }%
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{Page~\thepage\ of~\pageref{LastPage}}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyfoot[C]{Page~\thepage\ of~\pageref{LastPage}}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[1-12]

\appendix

\chapter{App-First}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're after a [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)-compatible version, you could fool TeX and use a different representation of the page counter for the appendix.

The MWE below uses `apppage` as the replacement representation at the start of the appendix via the following redefinition:

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{apppage}}
```

This allows the regular page counter to still continue as usual and therefore "keep `hyperref` happy." Here's an entire example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\newcounter{apppage}
\fancyhf{}% Clear fancy header/footer
\fancyfoot[C]{Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{lastpage}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
See~\pageref{applastpage} for the last page of the appendix.
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-4]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[5-8]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[9-12]
\label{lastpage}
\clearpage\appendix
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{apppage}}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{applastpage}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{First appendix}\lipsum[1-4]
\section{Second appendix}\lipsum[5-8]
\section{Last appendix}\lipsum[9-12]
\label{applastpage}
\end{document}
```

I've used `lastpage` as a basic label for the last page just as an illustration. For the last page of appendix and label `applastpage`, it would be better to use the [`lastpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage)'s `LastPage` label, or even the [`pageslts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts)'s `VeryLastPage` label.

Comment: For some reason. It's only saying Page 3 of 19 Pages. Even so that the report that is 54 pages

Comment: @mortenstarck: You'd have to supply more information than that, since I can't seem to replicate that problem using my minimal example above. That is, it works fine for me showing the correct page numbers in the footer. On a side note: if you wish to remove the hyperlink in the footer, use `\pageref*`.

Comment: This is the main document https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2230967/The%20SOMA%20Project.tex . I no it's a little messy.

Comment: @mortenstarck: There are so many other files missing that (most likely) includes necessary stuff that I'm unable to compile this. For example, are you including a `\label` on the last page, or are you using the `LastPage` label from [`lastpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage)? It's obvious that you're including the package, but your footer still refers to `\pageref*{applastpage}` and not `\pageref*{LastPage}`. How about including a bunch of `\lipsum`s to make up for all the other files and have something that I can compile. Then I'll look at it again.

Comment: If you would use a prefix or roman numbers in appendix, ```\usepackage{pageslts}
\lastpageref{LastPages}``` would be helpful

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple solution

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\begin{document}

\chapter{abc}

\kant

\cleardoublepage
\appendix
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{app}
\kant

\end{document}
```

Pages in the appendix will have "1 of 3" in the footer. You can customize at will. However, this won't please `hyperref`.